# Installing a 32 version of java on mac?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, java, 32-bit

I was recently was trying to use a library that needed a 32-bit version of java. I tried to get my version of java to use the 32-bit version by using the flag `-d32`. However, I received the error:

> Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
>   Please install the desired version.

I have been trying to find how to download the 32-bit version of java for mac, but with little success. Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question on Ask Different [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179224/step-to-step-guide-how-to-use-32bit-version-of-java-in-eclipse). There is no 32 bit Java any more.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want, but there is no such thing as 32 bit Java for OS X anymore. As the answer by greg-449 pointed out, the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) for Oracle only has a x64 installer.